# Battery and power supply in parallel

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, parallel

I have the following connection to power an AC load.

[image]

Will it work at all? I am concerned about the following points:

1. The battery may discharge to a low voltage and the power supply will charge the battery instead of providing enough power to the inverter.
2. This connection may overcharge the battery in the long run.
3. The system may become unstable due to different voltage levels (due to battery discharge.)

Please clarify the concerns pointed out.

Following are the design constraints.

- There are no charge controllers or current limiters for the battery.
- The DC supply will provide a constant current of 60A at 48V.
- The battery capacity is 100Ah
- Type:Lead acid
- Load is 1kW
- This connection is made parallel to provide more power to the inverter

Comment: *I have the following connection* - what does *connection* mean?

Comment: Do you want the power supply to change the battery or is it only intended to supply the inverter?

Comment: @brhans The system is supposed to do the both operations.

Answer (score 3):

Before we go into details, it's worth saying very clearly just in case - don't do this. This will likely damage the battery, as poses a fire risk.

What will happen in this configuration depends on the fine details of both the battery and the power supply.

Connecting things up like this basically results in a "highest voltage wins" situation. From a DC perspective, if the battery is at a higher voltage than the PSU, then the battery supplies the load. How the PSU responds depends on it, perhaps it will see no load and do nothing. If the difference is great enough then it could see an overvoltage and shut down. 
If the battery voltage is less than the PSU voltage, then the PSU will charge the battery like you say, until the battery voltage matches the PSU.

Depending on whether the voltage difference is uV or V impacts whether this is much of a problem. A fully charged 48V lead acid ought to have a 52V fully charged voltage, so probably what happens in this case is the battery supplies all the power, until it's discharged to 48V, at which point the PSU begins to take over. The droop of the PSU, and the discharge of the battery, usually cause a handover of the power from one to the other, rather than a step change. Assuming the PSU doesn't shutdown, which it might as this could well trigger an overvoltage, which it may or may not recover from.

The danger of fire happens when the PSU either returns after an outage, or in a sudden decrease in load. If the battery has discharged down to 46V or less, then the PSU will try its hardest to pull the line back up, charging the battery potentially dangerously fast. You'd have to check the datasheet, but a 100Ah lead acid battery might want to be charged at 30-40A, whereas your PSU might supply up to 60A, and this into a battery that might be dangerously over-discharged. This might occur even without a loss of PSU power. When loaded, the output will droop, this droop will be passed on to the battery, discharging the battery. So arbitrarily, let's say the PSU has an output voltage of 47.5V at 1kW, the battery discharges down to this. If the load is either removed or reduced, the PSU output will no longer have droop so it wants to be at 48V, but the battery is at 47.5V, with the difference resulting in the PSU pushing 1kW into the battery.

You haven't actually stated why there's the desire to have the battery as well as the PSU, but I assume the battery is a backup, to ensure power to the load is not lost if the PSU loses its input. In this case, as you've drawn it, the battery will be more or less flat all the time, so if the PSU cuts out it'll run the load, but not for very long, if at all. 
 The problem is, if you chose a battery with a charged voltage, then the risk of charging the battery too hard when the PSU restarts is increased. 
There are ways to operate a battery backup, these involve careful switching of the battery, to quickly connect the battery in if power is lost, as well as a separate charging circuit to recharge the battery while not in use.

Comment: some of these issues can be addressed with basic components like resistors and diodes, but the whole thing seems sparse on details and under-considered, as you eloquently describe.

Answer (score 0):

Wiring as per your schematic could cause battery damage / result in a fire.

Here's the altered schematic for safe operation.

[image]

The diodes D1 & D2 are required to ensure that there is no back-feed and that the battery takes over only when the power supply is down. They are Schottky diodes having low Vf.

The resistor R1 is required to limit the charging current.

Comment: In this circuit, it seems that D1 will be always in reverse bias since the PSU has a constant voltage of 46, am I right?  I guess this is a good arrangement for redundant power supply and not for "paralleled for higher current" Applications.

Comment: @nithin you didn't make any mention of wanting the battery for higher current requirements during peak load in your question. If this is what you want, I'd suggest you ask a new question on how to do this.

Comment: @LordTeddy You are correct. I've updated the question. Thanks for pointing out.